# Grouping large GPS data by 1 min

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas, time-series

```
date          object
lat          float64
lon          float64
speed        float64
direction    float64
```

In my `csv` file ,date is of following format `2016-04-29 11:45:21`
It shows date as object type . There are more than 10 records in every minute. so, I want to group together and apply mean of speed for every 1 min GPS data.
I try following code where datafile is pandas dataframe.

```
datafile.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1Min'))['speed'].mean()
```

The following error comes:

> TypeError: axis must be a DatetimeIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'

---

after editing as in comment and then datafile.head() shows[table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikWPg.jpg)[taxi table output after datafile.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikWPg.jpg)

Now i there are 1069 records from 06:35:20 to 06:59:59. I need to find the avg of speed of every 1 min data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `DateTimeIndex` from your `data` column using:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[: 'date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

However, you can probably leverage the builtin `.read_csv()` functionality, using `parse_dates=True` and `index_col=0` to read `date` as `index` and then parse the `index` (assuming date is first `column`).

Comment: but date shows 1970-01-01 00:00:00 for 2013-12-16 06:35:20. It doesnt show 2013

Comment: would help to show `df.head()`. See update - you can probably optimize your `.read_csv()` to parse dates properly when reading - see the docs http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: That worked but couldn't figure out yet. stucking in this for hours. When I use above command then output is as
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 2013-12-16 06:35:20 speed 96
consists of 1069 records. last record is
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001068 2013-12-16 06:59:59 speed 78
For  this, how can I group by 1 min since grouping by above code as asked in question gives only value ..

Comment: run `df.head()` and add the result to your question, need to see the output to understand what's up with your data.

Comment: I have edited. Since I cant post image due to account restrictions. there is link I have attached output in datafile.head()
link opens while clicking table output taxi

Comment: See update. Looks like `date` has not been set to `index` yet, so need to apply `to_datetime()` accordingly. Also updated the `read_csv` instructions.

Comment: Btw, it's better to just past the output of `df.head()` into your answer and use code formatting `{}` rather than posting an image.

Comment: Thank you finally works..
first parse the data then
datafile.index=pd.to_datetime(datafile.index,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
datafile.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1Min'))['speed'].mean()